# Laravel Exception is a 401 but response header is 500

Tags: php, laravel, api

i'm throwing a exception in my controller when the user is not authorized to make any action, i created a custom exception class to do it. i'm using this package too: https://github.com/esbenp/heimdal to format my response in a better format.
however, when i set my status code in my exception to 401, my response is 500.

```
<?php

namespace App\Acl\Exceptions;

use Exception;
use Throwable;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\UnauthorizedHttpException;

class UserUnauthorizedException extends Exception
{
    public function __construct($message = "", $code = 0, \Throwable $previous = null)
    {
        parent::__construct('you are not authorized to perform this action', 401, $previous);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the library you use. You could create an issue or submit a PR yourself otherwise you might have to switch to an alternative.

For reference, this is where the response status code is set: https://github.com/esbenp/heimdal/blob/master/src/Formatters/ExceptionFormatter.php#L13

**edit**: Basically you have to either extend the correct HttpException that is already being handled by the HttpExceptionFormatter in your library or update the configuration specifying that your Exception should be handled by it. The config could look something like this:

```
return [
    'formatters' => [
        \App\Acl\Exceptions\UserUnauthorizedException::class => \Optimus\Heimdal\Formatters\HttpExceptionFormatter::class,
        \Exception::class => \Optimus\Heimdal\Formatters\ExceptionFormatter::class,
    ]
];
```

This will use the HttpExceptionFormatter for your exception (and every class inheriting from it) whereas all other exceptions are handled by the generic ExceptionFormatter.

The default config can be found in the project's README: https://github.com/esbenp/heimdal#formatters

From this you can also gather that if you extend `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException` the HttpExceptionFormatter should kick in and should use the status code that you provide.

Comment: Acutally @Oliver_Maksimovic's answer is probably better. The HttpException-Listener will probably copy over the error code as status code.

Comment: Regarding your reaction. It's really not that bad. Treating all errors as 500 by default makes absolute sense as you might use those error codes for internal purposes rather than as status codes. This will prevent accidentally setting an invalid or wrong status code when you have unhandled domain exceptions. Exceptions with a *HttpException name or extending from a specific exception can then be processed like you intend. This is also what other frameworks do, I just missed the second formatter: https://github.com/esbenp/heimdal/blob/master/src/Formatters/HttpExceptionFormatter.php#L19

Comment: i really need set the status code, to handle some things in my frontend

Comment: Hey, I updated my answer with a sample config for using the HttpFormatter without extending from UnauthorizedHttpException. I hope it helps. Regarding your question with the challenge, I think you can type whatever you want unless you actually have a use for the `WWW-Authenticate`-header and do Challenge-based authentication

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
class UserUnauthorizedException extends Exception
```

try:

```
class UserUnauthorizedException extends UnauthorizedHttpException
```

Note that `401` that you are using in the constructor is not a HTTP code. It's an arbitrary value that you can set for custom evaluation somewhere else.

Comment: when i use the unauthorizedhttpexception the default value is:  __construct($challenge, $message = null, \Exception $previous = null, $code = 0) but i don't know what "challenge" means, what type of value i put there?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Acl\Exceptions;

use Exception;
use Throwable;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\UnauthorizedHttpException;

class UserUnauthorizedException extends UnauthorizedHttpException
{
public function __construct($message = "", $code = 0, \Throwable $previous = null)
{
    parent::__construct('you are not authorized to perform this action', 401, $previous);
}
```